# Problem Integrating Java SDK into Coldfusion

Tags: java, class, sdk, coldfusion

I am trying to integrate a digitalpersona java object into my coldfusion code to do fingerprint reading and saving. I am able to create the object from the jar and list out the methods, but I am not able to execute any methods on this object. Anyone with knowledge of Java and Coldfusion and how they interact together?

My cfscript is as follows: (the jar is in web-inf/lib)

```
testAll = createObject("java","com.digitalpersona.uareu.UareUGlobal");
writeDump(testAll);
testFid = createObject("java","com.digitalpersona.uareu.Fid");
writeDump(testFid);
testFmd = createObject("java","com.digitalpersona.uareu.Fmd");
writeDump(testFmd);
testEngine= createObject("java","com.digitalpersona.uareu.Engine");
writeDump(testEngine);
```

however, when I am trying to call a method from any of these objects (i.e. `testEngine.CreateFmd(toBinary(local.rawImageData),500,550,700,0,0,'ANSI_378_2004')`
), I am either getting a 500 error or I am getting a method not found error. I don't have enough Java expertise to be able to troubleshoot this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The dump for interface com.digitalpersona.uareu.Engine has the method in it:
```CreateFmd(com.digitalpersona.uareu.Fid, com.digitalpersona.uareu.Fmd$Format)
ReturnType  com.digitalpersona.uareu.Fmd

```
CreateFmd(byte[], int, int, int, int, int, com.digitalpersona.uareu.Fmd$Format)
```

ReturnType  com.digitalpersona.uareu.Fmd```

I also do not understand how to pass the com.digitalpersona.uareu.Fmd$Format parameters.  Again, sorry for this.. I am java impaired.

If I add an init() to the method, I get this:
`Unable to find a constructor for class com.digitalpersona.uareu.Engine that accepts parameters of type ( '' ).`

Comment: What is the dump for testEngine? Is the method in it?

Comment: See edit above.. thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
createObject("java","com.digitalpersona.uareu.UareUGlobal").init()
```

...and init() on the other objects?

Comment: See edit above.. thanks for the response!  The init for the UareUGlobal works (doesn't give me an error), but when I dump it out I get the same as the dump without the init.  I did try adding GetEngine() after the init and I got a 500 error.

Comment: Sometimes you need init(), sometimes you don't, and sometimes the init needs parameters.  Worth a shot.  I, too, am no Java expert, but usually a combination of <cfdump> of the java object, along with googling for com.thing.class gets some online docs that you can get more information with.  There's no magic bullet short of straight up documentation that is readable.

Comment: Thanks.. I have the online docs for the classes, but for some reason, it is not working.  Doing: testAll = createObject("java","com.digitalpersona.uareu.UareUGlobal").init();
  writeDump(testAll) gives me the methods and one of the methods is GetEngine().  But when I then do testAll.GetEngine() I get a 500 error.  I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: I figured out some of the problems. The ‘classes’ that I was trying to call methods on were actually interfaces which I can’t manipulate with creatobject. Now I’m just trying to figure out how to be able to use a Java interface in cf.